# Data Extension Contact ID?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Does Marketing cloud have a unique Identifier that can be used in Data Extensions when a contact is created? It seems odd that the only way I have been able to make use of a subscriber key is by using RandomBetween.

Comment: Which method you are using to create your subscribers?

Comment: Currently we are using a CloudPage for users to signup for our newsletter. They are not linked to Salesforce Connect because they are preleads in our instance since they are only signing up for a newsletter.